# Facing Issue when working with multimedia messages using amazon-connect-chatjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to get the Multimedia URL of S3, For that we use getAttachment API of amazon connect. I am using amazon-connect-chatjs, In these streams there is a method name downloadAttachment.This downloadAttachment method Wraps the [GetAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_GetAttachment.html) API. I invoke this method to get the URL,
What I Expect:
`try{
const chatAttachmentResponse = await controller.downloadAttachment({
attachmentId: response.data.Attachments[0].AttachmentId,
})
console.log("chatAttachmentResponse :: ", chatAttachmentResponse);
const { attachment } = chatAttachmentResponse.data;

```
              console.log("atachment Response :: ", attachment);
            }catch(e){
              console.log(e)`
```

When it hit this method I expect The response like [Response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_GetAttachment.html#API_GetAttachment_ResponseSyntax).

What I got:
When above method hit it return a Blob and starts downloading the file directly.